# Blazor display enum value in UI. value not showing

Tags: c#, .net, user-interface, razor, blazor

I am using blazor webclient to display an enum value in the UI. however when I run the client and a value is assigned nothing displays. I have taken this code from the GetName method. however this displays nothing on the page.

my razor component

```
<div>
    <p>Nationality: @Enum.GetName(typeof(Nationality), user.Nationality).ToString()</p>
    <p>Favourite Medium: @Enum.GetName(typeof(Medium), user.FavouriteMedium).ToString()</p>
</div>

@code {
 
    [Parameter]
    public UserViewModel user {get; set;}

}
```

when the page is loaded in no error is given and the value is shown as blank. I followed this method from the documentation here.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.getname?view=net-6.0

Edit.

The issue here was that there was a view model conversion point on my API that was not sending the enum value to the user model. because of this a 0 was being passed by the value where the enum values for these objects start at 1. therefore nothing was being displayed by the component where the @code block was inserted into the HTML.

thanks guys!

Comment: Is nothing displayed on the page?  Or is the value after `Nationality: ` not displayed?

Comment: I found the issue to be that the enum was getting a value of 0 when the first value of enum was set to 1. therefore no value was being returned from the GetName() method.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what your code is doing, but here's a dirty demo that shows you how to display an enum in a Blazor component.

```
@page "/"

<h1>Hello, your @nationality</h1>

<div>
    <button class="btn btn-dark" @onclick=ChangeNationality>Change Nationality</button>
</div>
@code {
    private Nationality nationality = Nationality.French;

    private void ChangeNationality()
        => nationality++;

    public enum Nationality
    {
        French,
        English,
        Welsh,
        Portuguese,
        Spanish
    }
}
```

Comment: The issue was with a 0 value being passed into the code. I explain this in the answer i posted earlier. =) thanks for your code!

Comment: NP - note you don't need to do the `@Enum.GetName(typeof(Nationality), user.Nationality).ToString()`, `@user.Nationality` will work.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue to be that the enum was getting a value of 0 from the model object when the first value of enum was set to 1. therefore no value was being returned from the GetName() method.